# Is this data function Vue or Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

i am very new to programming and have been doing a html project for school, when the professor stated that we are only supposed to use nodejs for our project. Here i am afraid that the function i used below is vue and not node, can anyone confirm?

```
data: function () {
              return {
                games: []
              };
            },
            mounted: function () {
              var that = this;
              $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({
                fullWidth: false,
                indicators: true
              });
              $.getJSON('/getgames').then(function (games) {
                that.games = games;
              });
            }
          });
```

Comment: see that bit of code is not helpful and I see jQuery and DOM calls which makes me wonder if it is actually node....

Comment: It's neither node nor vue, these are Javascript functions. But the object with `data` and `mounted` keys indicate it _might_ be the part of Vue component.

Comment: If the assessment is to be using node look at express js, vue is not node

Answer (score 1):

For starters, both Vue and Node are implementations of the JavaScript language. They are not their own language.

The instance you've shown is a script within a Vue component, it returns an empty "games" array in its data object, and invokes some carousel function once the component is mounted to the virtual DOM, probably some bootstrap doodad.

Comment: Let suggest a correction. Vue is NOT an implementation of javascript. It is a frontend javascript framework

Comment: Splitting hairs here aren't we?

Comment: Thank you for the expression, nice idiom. I don't think so though

Comment: You're just mad you got second comment haha

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing, but I guess I can render a suggestion here

Node.js you've mentioned is a **backend** technology

The snippet you've posted is, I'm 99.99% sure, a piece of **frontend** code. That makes me think that you cannot use it in your work

I don't know what your final goal is but I would advise following a good tutorial. Consider taking a look at these links:

- [Server-side website programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side)
- [VueJS Nodejs Tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2017/08/04/vuejs-nodejs-tutorial)

Good luck! :)